# How to Json.Encode a string and use it as Value for Hidden Input field?

Tags: razor

Does anyone see why this controller/view code is rendering incorrectly?

Controller:

```
ViewBag.tempString = "some temp string";

...
```

Razor View:

```
<input id="tempJson" type="hidden" value="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.tempString))" />
```

renders as:

```
<input id="tempJson" type="hidden" value some temp string"">
```

Comment: is it dotnet framework or dotnet core?

Comment: .NET Framework.

Comment: please see the answer. It should work in both dotnet framework and core.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  value of `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.tempString))` is already a string. So try like this:

```
value= @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.tempString))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use :

```
<input id="tempJson" type="hidden" value="@Html.Raw(ViewBag.tempString)" />
```